# Getting start date and end date of a week within month start and month end

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a program to get the start date and end date of a week when passing year and week number. Following is the code.

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $dto->setISODate($year, $week,0);
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  $dto->modify('+6 days');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}

$week_array = getStartAndEndDate(5,2017);
print_r($week_array);
```

This will output result as

```
Array ( [week_start] => 2017-01-29 [week_end] => 2017-02-04 )
```

But I need to get week in two part. For eg the result should be as follows

```
Array ( [week_start] => 2017-01-29 [week_end] => 2017-01-31)
Array ( [week_start] => 2017-02-01 [week_end] => 2017-02-04)
```

which means I need separate values for different months. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can a `week ends` within `2 days`

Comment: actually the week is not ending. What I need is to split the same week into two if the dates are in different months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compare two date by month and use `'t'` format to get the last day of the month later. Follow the [description of `date()` function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)  to learn more about all available formats and the example below.

Also it's better to use `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime` unless you really need the mutable version.

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year)
{
    $dto = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setISODate($year, $week, 0);
    $weekStart = $dto;
    $weekEnd = $dto->modify('+6 days');

    $ret = [];
    if ($weekStart->format('m') === $weekEnd->format('m')) {
        $ret[] = [
            'week_start' => $weekStart,
            'week_end' => $weekEnd,
        ];
    } else {
        $ret[] = [
            'week_start' => $weekStart->format('Y-m-d'),
            // 't' = the last day of the month.
            'week_end' => $weekStart->format('Y-m-t'),
        ];

        $ret[] = [
            // The first day of the month.
            'week_start' => $weekEnd->format('Y-m-01'),
            'week_end' => $weekEnd->format('Y-m-d'),
        ];
    }

    return $ret;
}
```